# Exercise in computation with macros: expansion not working as expected

Tags: macros, expansion

I'm studying macros and, as an exercise, I wanted to compute the successor of a number, represented as text, in binary, little endian (lsb first).
After big effort I devised this:

```
\def\finish#1\relax{#1}
\def\go#1{\toks0={}%
  \ifx#1\relax\toks0={1}\fi%
  \if0#1\toks0={1\finish}\fi%
  \if1#1\toks0={0\go}\fi%
  \the\toks0}
```

The idea is to scan the number from the left and apply the obvious transformations, recurring when needed and copying the rest of the number otherwise.
I use `\relax` as a marker for the end of the string: I was using `\end`, taking inspiration from the TeXbook, but it didn't work here.

It works correctly in the first cases: `\go\relax` and `\go0\relax` produce `1` as the successor of `0`, `\go1\relax` produces `01`.

Anyway, I can't understand why `\go01\relax` yields an empty output.
Manually following the expansion and even substituting its fragments in place give the correct `11`.
What am I missing?

Comment: For macro expansion mysteries like this I find the [`unravel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unravel) package rather useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your numbers are *big endian*, because they finish (in the sense of writing) with the most significant bit.

Let's see what happens with `\go01\relax`. The argument to `\go` is `0`, so we get

```
\toks0={}\ifx0\relax\toks0={1}\fi\if00\toks0={1\finish}\fi\if10\toks0={0\go}\fi\the\toks01\relax
```

Now try

```
\def\finish#1\relax{#1}
\def\go#1{\toks0={}%
  \ifx#1\relax\toks0={1}\fi
  \if0#1\toks0={1\finish}\fi
  \if1#1\toks0={0\go}\fi
  \the\toks0%
}

\toks1={Oops!}

\go01\relax

\bye
```

and check that TeX prints “Oops!”.

Do you see what's the problem? [This is a (curable) case of the *missing space syndrome*, which is a bit nastier than its companion *spurious space syndrome*](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113gregorio.pdf). Here's the cure: *Always put a blank space after a numeric constant* (The TeXbook, page 208).

```
\def\finish#1\relax{#1}
\def\go#1{\toks0={}%
  \ifx#1\relax\toks0={1}\fi
  \if0#1\toks0={1\finish}\fi
  \if1#1\toks0={0\go}\fi
  \the\toks0
}

0: \go0\relax

1: \go1\relax

01: \go01\relax

11: \go11\relax

011: \go011\relax

111: \go111\relax

\bye
```

[image]

You may enjoy looking at this fully expandable version.

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\finish#1\relax{#1}
\def\go#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {1}{\digit#1}%
}
\def\digit#1{%
  \if0#1%
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {1\finish}{0\go}%
}

0: \go0\relax

1: \go1\relax

01: \go01\relax

11: \go11\relax

011: \go011\relax

111: \go111\relax

\edef\test{\go10011101\relax}

{\tt\meaning\test}

\bye
```

Comment: Aaaargh! yes thanks! I think it's pretty clear now

Comment: @user9137 Raise their hand whoever has been bitten by this feature of the language! I raise mine, of course ‍♂️

Comment: @egreg  Me too. :-)

Comment: @user9137 I added a couple of references (I'm the author of the TUGboat paper).

Answer (score 6):

Here is another implementation of your task which is more simple and fully expandable because there is no setting to the toks register.

If you did it that way the first time, you wouldn't have any problems with the `\toks01` register.

```
\def\go#1{%
   \ifx#1\relax 1\expandafter\goF \fi
   \ifx#101\expandafter\goC
   \else  0\expandafter\go  % 1 converted to 0, do recursive \go
   \fi
}
\def\goF #1\go\fi{}   % \go Final, \relax scanned, 1 added, do nothing
\def\goC #1\relax{#1} % \go Copy, 0 converted to 1, copy rest

0: \go0\relax

1: \go1\relax

01: \go01\relax

11: \go11\relax

011: \go011\relax

111:  \go111\relax

11100:  \go11100\relax

1100110011:  \go1100110011\relax

000:  \go000\relax

\bye
```

We can combine the `\go` macro with the `\revers` macro and create the `\addone` macro which reads and prints binary numbers as we are used to:

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\revers#1#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\afterfi{\revers#2\relax}\fi#1}

\def\go#1{%
   \ifx#1\relax 1\expandafter\goF \fi
   \ifx#101\expandafter\goC
   \else  0\expandafter\go  % 1 converted to 0, do recursive \go
   \fi
}
\def\goF #1\go\fi{}   % \go Final, \relax scanned, do nothing
\def\goC #1\relax{#1} % \go Copy, 0 converted to 1, copy rest.

\def\addone#1{%
   \expandafter\revers \expanded{%
       \expandafter\go\expanded{\revers#1\relax}\relax}%
   \relax
}

0: \addone{0}    % prints 1

1: \addone{1}    % prints 10

10: \addone{10}  % prints 11

11: \addone{11}  % prints 100

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks. Combining it with the reverse is my actual next exercise, so I'm soon looking at your solution with attention. Btw, since many of you are mentioning "fully expandable", what does it mean? Does it have anything to do with the possibilities of combining it with other macros to make a sort of functional composition?

Comment: This solution also actually seems more in line with what I'd normally do. I did it with the token register because I didn't seem to be able to reach it this way.

Comment: "Fully expadable" macro means that the result of the macro is done only by macros or expandable primitives. Assignments (like `\def..`, `\toks0=..` etc. are done at main processor level and they are not expandable. The list of expandable primitives is in my document "TeX in the Nutshell" http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf section 12. You can try `\message{\yourmacro parameters}` in order to test the "fully expandable" feature, because `\message` expands its argument before printing it to the terminal and log file. And unexpandable commadns are printed without changes.

Answer (score 4):

As egreg already pointed out, with the directive `\the\toks0` TeX needs to know the number of the `\toks`-register denoted and therefore gathers (and hereby expands expandable) tokens that form a TeX *⟨number⟩*-quantity. Thus after encountering the digit `0` TeX does not spit out the content of the register `\toks0` but keeps gathering more digits belonging to the number denoting the `\toks`-register, hereby consuming tokens that belong to the argument of `\go`.
You can prevent this via `\the\toks0` , i.e., via  `\the\toks0⟨space⟩`.

Here is another fully expandable variant of Big-Endian-Incrementing of binary numbers which does without `\if..`-forking—instead forking is done by means of delimiter-matching of delimited arguments:

```tex
\def\go{\innergo{1}{0}{1}}
\def\innergo#1#2#3#4{%
    % #1 replacement for bit 0 
    % #2 replacement for bit 1
    % #3 digit to append when \relax is reached.
    % #4 current bit or \relax
  \ForkBit
  !#4!1!\relax!{#1\innergo{0}{1}{}}%      <- #4 (current bit) is 0
  !0!#4!\relax!{#2\innergo{#1}{#2}{#3}}%  <- #4 (current bit) is 1
  !0!1!#4!{#3}%                           <- #4 (current bit) is \relax
  !!!%
}%
\def\ForkBit#1!0!1!\relax!#2#3!!!{#2}%

101:  \go101\relax

001:  \go001\relax

111:  \go111\relax

11100:  \go11100\relax

1100110011:  \go1100110011\relax

00110011001100:  \go00110011001100\relax

000:  \go000\relax

\bye
```

[image]

If you wish trailing (significant) zeros to be removed from your Big-Endian-Number, you can probably try s.th. like this:

```tex
\def\go{\innergo{1}{0}{}{}}
\def\innergo#1#2#3#4#5{%
    % #1 replacement for bit 0 / digit to append when \relax is reached.
    % #2 replacement for bit 1
    % #3 symbol to gather when encountering bit 0
    % #4 replacements for bit 0 gathered so far
    % #5 current bit or \relax
  \ForkBit
  !#5!1!\relax!{#1\innergo{}{1}{0}{#4#3}}%    <- #5 (current bit) is 0
  !0!#5!\relax!{#4#2\innergo{#1}{#2}{#3}{}}%  <- #5 (current bit) is 1
  !0!1!#5!{#1}%                               <- #5 (current bit) is \relax
  !!!%
}%
\def\ForkBit#1!0!1!\relax!#2#3!!!{#2}%

101:  \go101\relax

001:  \go001\relax

111:  \go111\relax

11100:  \go11100\relax

1100110011:  \go1100110011\relax

00110011001100:  \go00110011001100\relax

000:  \go000\relax

\bye
```

[image]